# NullPointerException on using drawImage for different images

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, drawimage

Im trying to make a chess game in a JFrame. I have a problem whem i'm rendering the pieces using drawImage.

This is a part of the code for each piece

```
private Image img;
private int x, y;
public Tura(int x, int y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.img = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Rares/Documents/PieseSah/cal.png").getImage();
}
```

And this is how i'm displaying:

```
for(int y=0;y<8;y++)
      for(int x=0;x<8;x++)
           g.drawImage(p[y][x].getImage(), 37+x*81, 62+y*81, this);
```

If i use the same image for each piece everything is OK. If i use the right image for each piece i get NullPointerException at the drawImage line.

population of p array:

```
   for(int y=0;y<8;y++)
            for(int x=0;x<8;x++)
            {
                if(y == 1 || y == 6)
                    p[y][x] = new Pion(x,y);
                else if(y == 0 || y == 7)
                    switch(x)
                    {   
                        case 0: case 7: p[y][x] = new Tura(x,y);break;
                        case 1: case 6: p[y][x] = new Cal(x,y);break;
                        case 2: case 5: p[y][x] = new Nebun(x,y);break;
                        case 3: p[y][x] = new Regina(x,y);break;
                        case 4: p[y][x] = new Rege(x,y);break;
                    }
                else p[y][x] = new PiesaBlank(x,y);
            }
```

This code is for my jframe

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package tablasah;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author Rares
 */
public class Tabla extends JFrame {
    private PiesaSah[][] p = new PiesaSah[8][8];
    private Image dbImage;
    private Graphics dbg;
    public Tabla()
    {
        setTitle("Joc Sah");
        setSize(700,725);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        initializare();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
        paintComponent(dbg);
        g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(27, 52, 648, 648);
        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        g.drawLine(27, 133, 675, 133);
        g.drawLine(27, 214, 675, 214);
        g.drawLine(27, 295, 675, 295);
        g.drawLine(27, 376, 675, 376);
        g.drawLine(27, 457, 675, 457);
        g.drawLine(27, 538, 675, 538);
        g.drawLine(27, 619, 675, 619);

        g.drawLine(108, 52, 108, 700);
        g.drawLine(189, 52, 189, 700);
        g.drawLine(270, 52, 270, 700);
        g.drawLine(351, 52, 351, 700);
        g.drawLine(432, 52, 432, 700);
        g.drawLine(513, 52, 513, 700);
        g.drawLine(594, 52, 594, 700);

        for(int y=0;y<8;y++)
            for(int x=0;x<8;x++)
                g.drawImage(p[y][x].getImage(), 37+x*81, 62+y*81, this);
    }
    public void initializare()
    {
        for(int y=0;y<8;y++)
            for(int x=0;x<8;x++)
            {
                if(y == 1 || y == 6)
                    p[y][x] = new Pion(x,y);
                else if(y == 0 || y == 7)
                    switch(x)
                    {   
                        case 0: case 7: p[y][x] = new Tura(x,y);break;
                        case 1: case 6: p[y][x] = new Cal(x,y);break;
                        case 2: case 5: p[y][x] = new Nebun(x,y);break;
                        case 3: p[y][x] = new Regina(x,y);break;
                        case 4: p[y][x] = new Rege(x,y);break;
                    }
                else p[y][x] = new PiesaBlank(x,y);
            }
    }
    public PiesaSah[][] getPiesaSah()
    {
        return p;
    }
    public void afisareTabla()
    {   
        System.out.println("\n------------------------------------------\nAfisez:");
        for(int y=7;y>=-1;y--)
        {
            if(y==-1)
                System.out.print("          y/x");
            else
                System.out.print("           " + y + " ");
            for(int x=0;x<8;x++)
            {   
                if(y==-1)
                    System.out.print(" " + x);
                if(y>-1)
                    System.out.print(" " + p[y][x].getChar());
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
    }
    public int mutarePiesa()
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\nCe piesa vreti sa mutati?\nx=");
        int x = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("y=");
        int y = scanner.nextInt();
        if (p[y][x].getChar() == '-') {
            System.out.println("\nError: Nu exista piesa la acea locatie.");
            return 0;
        } else {
            System.out.println("\nPiesa selectata: " + p[y][x].getType() + "[" + p[y][x].getPosX() + "][" + p[y][x].getPosY() + "]");
            System.out.print("\nLa ce locatie vreti sa o mutati?\nx=");
            int z = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.print("y=");
            int w = scanner.nextInt();
            if (x == z && y == w) {
                System.out.println("\nError: Nu ai mutat piesa (aceeasi locatie).");
                return 0;
            } else if (p[w][z].getChar() != '-') {
                System.out.println("\nError: Exista deja o piesa pe acea locatie.");
                return 0;
            } else {
                if (p[y][x].verificareMutare(z, w) == 1) {
                    p[w][z] = p[y][x];
                    p[y][x] = new PiesaBlank(x, y);
                    System.out.println("\nMutare efectuata cu succes.");
                    this.afisareTabla();
                } else return 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Continuam? Da=1/Nu=0");
        return scanner.nextInt();
    }
}
```

This is a sample code for my queen

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package tablasah;

import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

/**
 *
 * @author Rares
 */
public class Regina implements PiesaSah {
    private final String type = "Regina";
    private final char c = 'r';
    private Image img;
    private int x, y;
    public Regina(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.img = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Rares/Documents/PieseSah/regina.png").getImage();
    }
    public char getChar()
    {
        return c;
    }
    public String getType()
    {
        return type;
    }
    public Image getImage()
    {
        return img;
    }
    public int getPosX()
    {
        return this.x;
    } 
    public int getPosY()
    {
        return this.y;
    }           
    public int verificareMutare(int x, int y)
    {
        if(y < 0 || x < 0 || y > 8 || x > 8)
        {    
            System.out.println("Error mutare " + this.getType());
            return 0;
        }
        else if ((x-this.x == y-this.y) || (this.x == x && ((y > this.y) || (y < this.y))) || (this.y == y && ((x > this.x) || (x < this.x))))
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            return 1;
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Error mutare " + this.getType());
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And the interface for my pieces

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package tablasah;

import java.awt.Image;

/**
 *
 * @author Rares
 */
public interface PiesaSah {
    public int verificareMutare(int x, int y);  
    public int getPosX();
    public int getPosY();
    public Image getImage();
    public String getType();
    public char getChar();
}
```

The exception ->

```
   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
   at tablasah.Tabla.paintComponent(Tabla.java:65)
at tablasah.Tabla.paint(Tabla.java:36)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:819)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:796)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:796)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:769)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:718)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(RepaintManager.java:62)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1677)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at     java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: How are you assigning the image with your code that doesn't work? In your example, you're hard-coding a single image, which from what we can infer, works, but we still don't know how you're assigning it otherwise.

Comment: How is the p array constructed? Are the images actually loaded. Try using ImageIO to read the images, as it will throw an IOException when something goes wrong

Comment: The code works, well sort of. Im seeing the images loading in my JFrame. I used ImageIO without getting any errors. When i use a single image for the entire matrix i dont get errors. When i use different images i get the error.

Comment: You're getting a NullPointerException because you're trying to call the getImage method on an array position which is empty (null) but your code samples do not tell us how your array is being populated with data, nor does it show how you load different images. Please add all of your code relevant to this problem.

Comment: i've added the code relevant to the population of the p array

Comment: Code looks OK. Please post the full stack trace, and/or more code.

Comment: i've posted the full exception, there isnt any much code to add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by removing from the constructors of the pieces this part of code

```
this.img = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Rares/Documents/PieseSah/cal.png").getImage();
```

and adding it to my getImage method

like

```
public Image getImage()
{
    this.img = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Rares/Documents/PieseSah/cal.png").getImage();
    return img;
}
```

Isnt this odd? All of the constructors we're called..